# How set up speaking links for news in TYPO3 9

Tags: typo3, tx-news, typo3-9.x

Is it possible to setup speaking urls in TYPO3 9 for EXT:tt_news as it was with RealUrl in prev versions?

Comment: so are you using tt_news or news?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a route enhancer in your site configuration. There should be a `config.yaml` in your project after you created it in TYPO3 backend (Under "Site Configuration" -> "Sites").

After that, you can find a working example in the documentation (for news) here:
[Route Enhacer Documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/9.5/Feature-86365-RoutingEnhancersAndAspects.html#extbase-plugin-enhancer)

A working route enhancer I have currently implemented for example looks like this:

```
NewsPlugin:
  type: Extbase
  extension: News
  plugin: Pi1
  routes:
    - { routePath: '/blog/{news_title}', _controller: 'News::detail', _arguments: {'news_title': 'news'} }
  aspects:
    news_title:
      type: PersistedAliasMapper
      tableName: 'tx_news_domain_model_news'
      routeFieldName: 'path_segment'
      routeValuePrefix: '/'
```

Bear in mind, that this configuration is stripped of some of the examples in documentation and doesn't support pagination.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at this manual "[Routing Enhancers and Aspects](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/9.5/Feature-86365-RoutingEnhancersAndAspects.html)"